# How to make Pinterest-style grid using Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have a problem - I need to implement Pinterest-style grid or at least just grid. How I can be done with Titanium, any ideas?

PS There is a module https://github.com/mpociot/TiCollectionView which does exactly the same what I need. It's perfect on Android but really buggy on iOs.

Comment: Do your images all have the same size?

Comment: They have the same size but I'd like to make it in a Pinterest style with different size later.

Comment: If all your images have the same size it should be easy to develop a dynamic grid in your controller. Just add a scrollview to your view. Then start to create the views in a loop. This is relatively easy to achieve for same-size images and a bit more complex for differently sized images.

Comment: Actually its pretty easy to make Pinterest-style grid using ScrollView but the problem it that ScrollView is really slow.

Comment: I guess this depends mainly on the number of items. Although Titanium's performance is not good in general either.. But I have no idea how you could substitute the scrollview..